# Construction an Arc in Eyeshot

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, eyeshot

I am trying to construct the arcs applying Eyeshot 12. 
I use the constructor: Arc(Plane, 2D center point, 2D start point, 2D end point).
I have two arcs. The **end point** of one of them is exactly the same as the **start point** of the another one. In spite of that, Eyeshot constructs the arcs with **significant gap** between these points. Is this a bug , or I am doing somethying wrong?

The parameters of my arcs are as follows:
Arc1: 2D center point = (`-0.655572, 0.160451`),
      2D start point = (`-0.008477,  0.049511`),
      2D end point = (`0.000385, 0.1271105`).
Arc2: 2D center point = (`-1.789206, 0.218072`),
      2D start point = (`0.000385, 0.1271105`),
      2D end point = (`0.002240, 0.177704`).

Answer (score 1):

The radius of each arc is defined as the distance between the center and the startpoint. So if you pass an endpoint that has a different distance from the center, the arc will not pass through the endpoint.
In both of your arcs, these distances are different, and that's why you get the gap:

- C1-Sta1 = 0.65653607869255759
- C1-End1 = 0.65680375668022029
- C2-Sta2 = 1.7919012087063424
- C2-End2 = 1.7919007635301683

So if you want the first arc to end at the point in common with the second arc, you need to treat that point as a start, and then revert the arc's orientation:

```
            Plane pl = Plane.XY;

            Point2D c1 = new Point2D(-0.655572, 0.160451);
            Point2D c2 = new Point2D(-1.789206, 0.218072);

            Point2D s1 = new Point2D(-0.008477, 0.049511);
            Point2D s2 = new Point2D(0.000385, 0.1271105);

            Point2D e1 = new Point2D(0.000385, 0.1271105);
            Point2D e2 = new Point2D(0.002240, 0.177704);

            Plane plInv = new Plane(pl.Origin, pl.AxisY, pl.AxisX);
            Arc a1 = new Arc(plInv,plInv.Project(pl.PointAt(c1)), plInv.Project(pl.PointAt(e1)), plInv.Project(pl.PointAt(s1)));
            a1.Reverse();

            Arc a2 = new Arc(pl,c2,s2,e2);
```